# How I can prepand an html tag before an element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a page Initially with buttons and then a table (ag-grid).

```
<div class="row"> <-- Button -->
   <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
   </button>
</div>
<div class="" ag-grid="ag_grid_options" ></div> <!-- Table-- >
```

I want to create a directive (a button which does something), which is alligned with the above button.

I have created this directive:

```
app.directive('exportData', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"> GOD IS HERE </button>',
        link: function(scope) {

        }
    };
});
```

and I have modified the tag for ag-grid-option to something like this:

```
<div class="" ag-grid="ag_grid_options" export-data></div>
```

But the button comes in new line instead of alligning with the previous button. So my question is, Is there a way to prepand the button with the previous button?

I have requirement of using this as attribute only of ag-grid. Can anyone please help me here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
app.directive('exportData', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, model){
            element.parent().prepend('<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"> GOD IS HERE </button>');
        };
     }
});
```

A better solution can be to create a wrapper:

```
app.directive('exportData', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, model){
            // Create a wrapper
            var wrapper = $('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
            element.wrap(wrapper);

            // Compile and attach the button
            var button = $('<button class="btn"> GOD IS HERE </button>');
            element.before(button);
        };
     }
});
```

Comment: ok..this seems to be working fine.. but when i add ng-click to the prepend directive, that doesn't seems to be working. 
<button class="" ng-click="someFunction()"> Test </button> doesnt work

Comment: You can compile it before using `$compile` service, something like: `var button = $compile($('<button class="btn"> GOD IS HERE </button>'))(scope)`